# Cannot pivot the data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame looking like this
[image]

I want to transform it to have time as index (no change) but as columns I want to have **sub_transformer**. I used pivot() from pandas but I get an error.

```
df2.pivot(index = 'time',columns = 'sub_transformer',values='value')
KeyError: 'time'
```

or i tried using

```
df2.reset_index().pivot(index = 'time',columns = 'sub_transformer',values='value') 
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Comment: Try: `df2.reset_index().pivot(index = 'time',columns = 'sub_transformer',values='value')`

Comment: @ThePyGuy now i get ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape